# How do I create a VPN?

Tags: macos, networking, vpn

I need to visit a webpage which throws a 403 at me, I was told I could visit it only when in the Local Area Network where the server is or by making a VPN connection. I only have a very global idea of what a VPN is and don't know how to make one. Going to the LAN is not an option. I'm on a Mac (OS X 10.6.8).

Comment: Start by talking to the network admin to determine what VPN server(s) they are running

Comment: And what should they give me? <strikethrough>A URL? An IP-address?</strikethrough> These are functionally the same. But I hope you understand what I mean. @RowlandShaw

Comment: They should probably give you the type of VPN they are running, the settings and hopefully let you know what username/password/cert you need to connect to the VPN. Basically, if they allow you to connect to  the VPN, they need to provide you with info/software that'll let you do it. So talk to your Network Admin to get support on this.

Comment: I'd expect them to say somehting like "use this checkpoint VPN client" or "use Windows VPN connection to this IP" or "we don't allow VPN connections" or something along those lines

Comment: I was told by a teacher to make a VPN connection. So they would have to allow it. I already found out how to do it, turns out it was quite simple.

Answer (score 2):

I searched around on the public part of the website to be able to answer Rowland Shaw's comment. I found a `.pcf` file. After looking at the installation procedure I figured it was a configuration file and tried to open it with a text editor. I then googled for `mac vpn client` and learned Mac has native support for it. I created a new network interface and guessed `host` in the pcf file had to be `Server Address` in System Preferences, I already knew the username and password and tried to connect. I then learned I needed to give it a Group Secret (or Shared Secret, I believe) (and a group name. But that's just given in the pcf). That was a bit more difficult. In the pcf file it said `enc_groupPwd`. I figured that meant encrypted but tried anyway. `Group Secret incorrect`. After that I found [this guide](http://coding-journal.com/cisco-vpn-client-on-mac-os-x-10-6-you-dont-need-it/) which helped me out. It has a link to [this decoder for Cisco encoded Group Secrets](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/bin/cisco-decode), which uses [this decoder (source code)](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~massar/soft/cisco-decrypt.c). In case the server hosting the source code deletes the file or goes down: Here it is:

```
/* Decoder for password encoding of Cisco VPN client.
   Copyright (C) 2005 Maurice Massar
   Thanks to HAL-9000@evilscientists.de for decoding and posting the algorithm!

   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.

   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   GNU General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
   along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
   Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
*/

/*
   Requires libgcrypt version 1.1.90 or newer
   Compile with:
    gcc -Wall -o cisco-decrypt cisco-decrypt.c $(libgcrypt-config --libs --cflags)
   Usage:
    ./cisco-decrypt DEADBEEF...012345678 424242...7261
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gcrypt.h>
#include <errno.h>

int hex2bin_c(unsigned int c)
{
    if ((c >= '0')&&(c <= '9'))
        return c - '0';
    if ((c >= 'A')&&(c <= 'F'))
        return c - 'A' + 10;
    if ((c >= 'a')&&(c <= 'f'))
        return c - 'a' + 10;
    return -1;
}

int hex2bin(const char *str, char **bin, int *len)
{
    char *p;
    int i, l;

    if (!bin)
        return EINVAL;

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (hex2bin_c(str[i]) == -1)
            return EINVAL;

    l = i;
    if ((l & 1) != 0)
        return EINVAL;
    l /= 2;

    p = malloc(l);
    if (p == NULL)
        return ENOMEM;

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
        p[i] = hex2bin_c(str[i*2]) << 4 | hex2bin_c(str[i*2+1]);

    *bin = p;
    if (len)
        *len = l;

    return 0;
}

int c_decrypt(char *ct, int len, char **resp, char *reslenp)
{
    const char *h1  = ct;
    const char *h4  = ct + 20;
    const char *enc = ct + 40;

    char ht[20], h2[20], h3[20], key[24];
    const char *iv = h1;
    char *res;
    gcry_cipher_hd_t ctx;
    int reslen;

    if (len < 48)
        return 0;
    len -= 40;

    memcpy(ht, h1, 20);

    ht[19]++;
    gcry_md_hash_buffer(GCRY_MD_SHA1, h2, ht, 20);

    ht[19] += 2;
    gcry_md_hash_buffer(GCRY_MD_SHA1, h3, ht, 20);

    memcpy(key, h2, 20);
    memcpy(key+20, h3, 4);
    /* who cares about parity anyway? */

    gcry_md_hash_buffer(GCRY_MD_SHA1, ht, enc, len);

    if (memcmp(h4, ht, 20) != 0)
        return -1;

    res = malloc(len);
    if (res == NULL)
        return -1;

    gcry_cipher_open(&ctx, GCRY_CIPHER_3DES, GCRY_CIPHER_MODE_CBC, 0);
    gcry_cipher_setkey(ctx, key, 24);
    gcry_cipher_setiv(ctx, iv, 8);
    gcry_cipher_decrypt(ctx, (unsigned char *)res, len, (unsigned char *)enc, len);
    gcry_cipher_close(ctx);

    reslen = len - res[len-1];
    res[reslen] = '\0';

    if (resp)
        *resp = res;
    if (reslenp)
        *reslenp = reslen;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, len, ret = 0;
    char *bin, *pw;

    gcry_check_version(NULL);

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        ret = hex2bin(argv[i], &bin, &len);
        if (ret != 0) {
            perror("decoding input");
            continue;
        }
        ret = c_decrypt(bin, len, &pw, NULL);
        free(bin);
        if (ret != 0) {
            perror("decrypting input");
            continue;
        }
        printf("%s\n", pw);
        free(pw);
    }

    exit(ret != 0);
}
```

If I somehow violated the license please leave a comment (or edit this post).